# How to open a drawer from another component in react material?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-component

I want to open a drawer from another component in react Material-UI. The wanted result is that after clicking on a button (located in the module rete.js), the drawer should open (chatbotdrawer.js component).

Instead, it displays another button with the label "test your bot here". I have tried it with "open" and "state" props, but I am not able to change the child components status. Any ideas?

Here is my rete.js module code:

```
 const Rete = (props) => { 
   const [showDrawer, setShowDrawer] = useState(false);
    
  const saveButtonHandler1 = async () => {
    const showDrawerHandler = () => {
      setShowDrawer(!showDrawer);
    };
    
    showDrawerHandler()
    return (
      {showDrawer ? <ChatbotDrawer state={true} /> : null}
)}
```

And here is my chatbotdrawer.js code:

```
  export default function SwipeableTemporaryDrawer(props) {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        right: false,
      });

  const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => (event) => {
    if (
      event &&
      event.type === "keydown" &&
      (event.key === "Tab" || event.key === "Shift")
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setState({ ...state, [anchor]: open });
  };

  const list = (anchor) => (
    <div
      className={clsx(classes.list, {
        [classes.fullList]:
          anchor === "test your bot here" || anchor === "right",
      })}
      role="presentation"
      onBlur={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
    >
      <Chatbot />
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {["right"].map((anchor) => (
        <React.Fragment key={anchor}>
          <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}>
            {"test your bot here"}
          </Button>
          <SwipeableDrawer
            anchor={anchor}
            open={state[anchor]}
            onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
            onOpen={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}
          >
            {list(anchor)}
          </SwipeableDrawer>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you include a codesandbox for this?

Comment: might be difficult because the related code has many dependencies, it wouldn't work. But let me ask a simpler question: How can I change the "right" state via props:


const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        right: false,
      });

Comment: @RainerWinkler the fastest way is `let newstate = {right: !state.right}; setState(newstate)`.

Comment: `setState(prev => {...prev, right: !prev.right})` will work too.